# How to automatically fetch data from json server when data gets updated in it in react js

Tags: reactjs, forms, fetch, json-server

I have a form and I have a table in my UI.
When the user updates data in the form, Im storing that in JSON server. (The code for this is in Add_task_form.js).

In View_tasks.js I have fetched the data from JSON server and displayed that in a table.

When a user updates the form, its not updating in the table, only when i refresh the page it gets updated.
What to do for automatic updating in table.

Please help me in resolving this issue.
Thank you in Advance.

[snippet of my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz05C.png)

App.js code -

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import View_tasks from './components/View_tasks'

function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <Header title='Task Tracker' />
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js -

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useState } from "react";
import Add_task_form from "./Add_task_form";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import View_tasks from './View_tasks';

const Header = (props) => {

  const [show_add_task, set_show_add_task] = useState(false)

  const toggle_show_add_task = () => {
    set_show_add_task( ! show_add_task ) ;
    console.log(show_add_task)
  }

  return (
    <>
    <header className='header_align'>
        {props.title}
        <button onClick={ () => {toggle_show_add_task() } }>Add Task </button>
    </header>

    { show_add_task && <Add_task_form /> }

    <View_tasks />
  
    </>
  )
}

Header.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Task Tracker' ,
}

Header.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
  
export default Header
```

Add_task_form.js -

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Add_task_form = () => {

    const [title, set_title] = useState('')
    const [datetime, set_datetime] = useState(' ')
    const [reminder, set_reminder] = useState(false)

    const add_task_fn = async(e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault() ;
        console.log(title)
        console.log(datetime)
        console.log(reminder)

        const data = {
            title: title,
            date: datetime,
            reminder: reminder
        }

        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks'  ,{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: 
            {
                'content-type' : 'application/json',
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(data)

        } )

    }

  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={ add_task_fn }> 
            <br />
            <div className="lbl_inp_align">
            <label> Enter Title </label>
            <input type="text" value={title} onChange = { (e) => set_title( e.target.value ) } required />
            </div>
            <br />

            <div className="lbl_inp_align">
            <label> Enter Date and Time </label>
            <input type="datetime-local" step="1" value={datetime} onChange = { (e) => set_datetime(e.target.value) } required />
            </div>
            <br />

            <div className="lbl_inp_align">
            <label> Set Reminder </label>
            <input type="checkbox" value={reminder} onChange = { (e) => set_reminder(e.currentTarget.checked) } />
            </div>
            <br />

            <div className="lbl_inp_align">
            <button>Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        
    </>
  )
}

export default Add_task_form
```

View_tasks.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const View_tasks = () => {

  const [tasks,settasks] = useState([])

  useEffect( () => {
    const fetchtasks = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks')
      const data = await res.json() ;
      settasks(data)
      
    }
    console.log(fetchtasks())

  },[] )



  return (
<>

    
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TASK TITLE</th>
        <th>Date and Time</th>
        <th>Reminder</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

    <tbody>
    { tasks.map( (task) => (
      <tr key={task.id}>
      <td> { task.title } </td>
      <td> { task.date } </td>
      <td> { task.reminder ? 'Pls remind' : 'No reminder' } </td>
      </tr>
    ) ) }
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </>
  )
}

export default View_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem...

1. Whenever an add request is made by clicking on the submit button, and if the response from the server is successful then you directly call the get API to get the updated data.
2. The second way is, when an add request is made then in the response of that API send whole updated data and directly display that response in your table so there is no need to call get API post to add API.

```js
const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('name', JSON.stringify(fields?.categoryName));
        formData.append('description', JSON.stringify(fields?.description));
        formData.append('image', file);
        setIsSubmitLoading(true);
        const data = await api(true).addCategory({
          data: formData,
        });
        if (data) {
          getData(generalData);
          onOk('add');
          setIsSubmitLoading(false);
        }
```

Here getData is the function that I created to call the get API.

Comment: how do I call the get API in Add_task_form.js

Comment: See once the add api is executed successfully then call the get API (the thing which is done inside the useEffect of your view_tasks.js) in "add_task_fn" only and just display the updated data inside the table by passed the updated values to the tasks state

Comment: I understand what you said, but not sure how to call the get API in "add_task_fn" . Can you show me an example

Comment: yes I edited the comment please see the updated comment